# File scan error in Orbeon Community Edition

Tags: orbeon

I can't upload file into my form in Orbeon 2021.1 CE. After upload i get generic error message about contacting administrator. In log i get message:

`Feature is not enabled in this version of the product: File scan API`

`Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException`

Why my CE version trying run PE feature? Is some way to turn off File scan?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Obviously, this should not happen. We are tracking this as [#5516](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5516).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug: that error should not have been reported in the log, and the bug is now fixed ([#5516](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5516)).

Note that the error being reported in the log didn't prevent the upload functionality from working, so should you see this in the log, you can either upgrade to a version that includes the fix, or ignore the exception.